# I get segmentation fault, when i compile cuda code

Tags: cuda, segmentation-fault

Programm ought to count pi using CUDA, i get segmentation error, when i try to show result of calculations. Why does it happens and how i should allocate memory properly?

```
// System includes
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define CUDA_FLOAT float
#define dx 0.1f
#define BLOCK_SIZE 16
#define GRID_SIZE 1
#define THREAD_SIZE 1
__global__ void pi_kern(CUDA_FLOAT *res)
{
    int n = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * BLOCK_SIZE; //start
    CUDA_FLOAT x0 = n * 1.f / (BLOCK_SIZE * GRID_SIZE * THREAD_SIZE); //integrating step
    CUDA_FLOAT s = 0; // Value of integrating on the segment for given thread
    CUDA_FLOAT x1, y1;
    CUDA_FLOAT y0;
    for (int i=0; i < THREAD_SIZE; i++)
    {
        x1 = x0 + dx;
        y1 = sqrtf(1 - x1 * x1);
        s += (y0 + y1) * dx / 2.f;
        x0 = x1; y0 = y1;
    }
    res[n] = s;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{   
    printf("[center-of-mass] - Starting\n");
    CUDA_FLOAT* data;
    CUDA_FLOAT* d_data;
    cudaMalloc ((void **) &data, 256*sizeof(CUDA_FLOAT));
    cudaMalloc ((void **) &d_data, 256*sizeof(CUDA_FLOAT));
    cudaMemcpy(d_data, data,256*sizeof(CUDA_FLOAT), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice); 
    dim3 block = dim3(BLOCK_SIZE);
    dim3 grid = dim3(GRID_SIZE*THREAD_SIZE/BLOCK_SIZE);
    pi_kern<<<grid, block>>> (d_data);
    cudaMemcpy(data, d_data, 256*sizeof( float ),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost );
    //cudaFree(d_data);
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    {
        cout << data[i]; 
    }
}
```

I don't know where the problem is, it's my first cuda project.

Comment: You are allocating data on the device. That memory isn’t accessible from host. And please describe your problem better. You aren’t getting a segfault during compilation, you are getting it when you run the code. That isn’t the same thing

Comment: You have quite a few errors in your code. The most important ones are that you allocate both arrays in device (GPU) memory. You should allocate one on host (CPU) memory, e.g. with regular `malloc` and the other one (d_data) on the device. The second big error is that your grid dimensions are rounded down to zero, which is obviously not what you want. I would advise you to check out some [CUDA sample](https://github.com/NVIDIA/cuda-samples) codes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

data is allocated on GPU like d_data. So cudamemcpy with cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost will crash.

To avoid this kind of error, you can use cudaMallocManaged. This allows you to read/write to your buffer from the host and the device without having to worry about memory management. No more need of cudamemcpy!

Read more here : https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/unified-memory-cuda-beginners/